# Oracle 11g XE installation on docker RHEL 7 image

Tags: unix, oracle11g, docker

While installing oracle 11g XE on docker i am getting the error.

Following are the output:-

```
/etc/init.d/oracle-xe configure

Oracle Database 11g Express Edition Configuration
This will configure on-boot properties of Oracle Database 11g Express
Edition. The following questions will determine whether the database should
be starting upon system boot, the ports it will use, and the passwords that
will be used for database accounts. Press to accept the defaults.
Ctrl-C will abort.

Specify the HTTP port that will be used for Oracle Application Express [8080]:8080

Specify a port that will be used for the database listener [1521]:1521

Specify a password to be used for database accounts. Note that the same
password will be used for SYS and SYSTEM. Oracle recommends the use of
different passwords for each database account. This can be done after
initial configuration:
Confirm the password:

Do you want Oracle Database 11g Express Edition to be started on boot (y/n) [y]:y

Starting Oracle Net Listener...Done
Configuring database...
Database Configuration failed. Look into /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log for details


[root@b7c63c4e1da8 Disk1]# cd /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/log


[root@b7c63c4e1da8 log]# ls


CloneRmanRestore.log cloneDBCreation.log postDBCreation.log postScripts.log


[root@b7c63c4e1da8 log]# cat CloneRmanRestore.log


ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system

select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual

*

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

declare
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0

select TO_CHAR(systimestamp,'YYYYMMDD HH:MI:SS') from dual
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01034: ORACLE not available
Process ID: 0
Session ID: 0 Serial number: 0
```

One of the possible solution that I got was to mount the temp file to provide extra space to it which only contains 6GB approx in the docker. But i am unable to mount the memory in docker.

Comment: This question is better ask in the [Unix Stack](http://unix.stackexchange.com/tour) or in the [Professional Server Management Stack](http://serverfault.com/tour)

Comment: You may take a look at one of the working images at the hub and compare with your setup. For example, https://hub.docker.com/r/wnameless/oracle-xe-11g/ works well for me.

Comment: I tried it but am unable to solve the memory problem. I am getting the error :- ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system.

Answer (score 0):

```
Got the solution for the same :- 
we have to modify the files init.ora and initXETemp.ora at the path /u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/xe/config/scripts  
with the values :- 
###########################################
 # Miscellaneous
###########################################
compatible=11.2.0.0.0
diagnostic_dest=/u01/app/oracle
#memory_target=1073741824
pga_aggregate_target=200540160
sga_target=601620480
```

Answer (score 0):

You may encounter

```
ORA-00845: MEMORY_TARGET not supported on this system
```

when starting Oracle DB in an unprivileged container.  Try running the container with the --privileged flag, e.g.

```
docker run --name oracle12 --hostname oracledb --privileged local/oracle12:12.1.0.2
```